# Is there a way to set the cursor address in IDA Pro?

Tags: ida, idapython

In the same way that `ScreenEA()` returns the current cursor address, is there a way to *set* the address? Something that would resemble `SetScreenEA()`?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use [`Jump`](https://www.hex-rays.com/products/ida/support/idadoc/194.shtml) for IDC or [`idc.Jump`](https://www.hex-rays.com/products/ida/support/idapython_docs/idc-module.html#Jump) for ida python.

Answer (score 3):

Updating answer for IDA Pro version 7.5, using Python 3:

- [`ida_kernwin.jumpto(ea)`](https://www.hex-rays.com/products/ida/support/idapython_docs/ida_kernwin.html#ida_kernwin.jumpto)